# Upgrade to Web Application project - custom controls not found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

After converting a web site project to web application (alongside an upgrade from VS2008 to VS2012) I am now having a little trouble with a host of errors telling me my custom (inherited) controls are not declared...

```
'<nameofcontrol>' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

I've removed all other errors that I am aware of (duplicate class names etc.) but the error list truncates at 100 so I can't be 100% sure.

My custom controls aren't .ascx files - just .vb classes that were historically in my app_code folder. I'd extended the functionality of existing WebControls by adding extra parameters. I also had the following in my web.config

```
<add tagPrefix="cst" namespace="myproject.Controls"/>
```

and everything worked great. Now it doesn't, what do I need to change?

I've tried a few variations of the above, adding `assembly="projectname"` - verifying that the project name dll is created properly in the bin folder.. but that didn't change anything. I've also tried placing similar to the above directly in the .aspx page under a register directive. If I misspell the namespace I get a different error (namespace doesn't contain any public members..) so it looks like it's finding the correct place for the controls.. but in the markup intellisense I get `Element '<nameofcontrol>' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Select your custom controls folder,(in my case it was Old_App_Code folder) then go to Project>>"Convert to Web Application" and the errors were gone.  Hope this will help some one

Answer (score 0):

Rename `App_Code` folder to different name (e.g. `AppCode`).

More info here: http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html

Comment: Thanks - I used the 'convert to web application' functionality which already renamed App_Code to Old_App_Code, so I'm not sure if this is an issue?